# Drupal 8 / CiviCRM ; Directories that need to be manually created?

Tags: civicrm.settings.php, drupal-8

I've created a d8/civi site on all three of bionic/eoam/focal and now have worked out the variances between them to the state that I now have an operational

Comment: Hi, I think your question got cut off. Can you edit to include the rest of it?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind....

I was accidentally using the drush-10 and I see that drush-8 is recommended.

That fixed my woes.

composer require drush/drush:^8